# What does impl trait X for Y as Z mean inside of Substrate's decl_storage macro?

Tags: rust, substrate

What does `as Indices` mean in the [following Substrate storage definition](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/89a9556e30404a2772b9e235c631179f0c5e8d78/srml/indices/src/lib.rs#L91)?

```rust
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as Indices { ... }
}
```

I have read the **Advanced Traits** section in the docs but the syntax for `trait` keyword doesn't consider any option labeled as `as`.

Comment: Where did you find that code? That is not syntactically valid Rust, unless it's inside a macro of some sort.

Comment: @E_net4 , hmm, well it is part of a macro, but in its body. I have posted the link to the source

Comment: Once inside a macro, it's the macro itself that defines what syntax to accept.

Comment: [`decl_storage` proc_macro](https://github.com/holygits/substrate/blob/2ad85daba580cd0248013be6351f1a81cef62fd6/srml/support/procedural/src/lib.rs#L56) , [`decl_storage_impl`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e0daf600287f1212d2c41a5b3d1b92921391e7ab/core/storage/procedural/src/storage/transformation.rs#L51)

Answer (score 2):

The line `trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as NAME` is macro magic. That line as written is not valid Rust, but it gets converted to valid Rust code through the `decl_storage!` macro.

Ultimately, `as Indices` makes it so that Substrate generates a user friendly alias (`Indices`) in the Substrate metadata for this storage item.

For example, you could name your storage something like this:

```rust
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as KittyStorage {
        Value: map T::AccountId => u64;
    }
}
```

It would appear in the Polkadot UI like so:

[image]

The name you choose here does not matter other than how you want your storage name to appear to the outside world.